# Use git to deploy updates to my site directory through cPanel

Tags: cpanel, github, git

I am trying to workout how I can get my `public_html` dir to update directly from a git repository.  On looking through Google at the tutorials available they all include the step of a local machine - I do not want this as the file will be updated via GITHUB GUI and the editor.

Currently I have my `git` folder called `git` within my `public_html` dir and within the `hooks/post-receive` I have the line of code below but I am unsure how to link it all back to the `github` repository and have it update if there is a file to be updated.

**hooks/post-receive:**
`GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/userName/public_html git checkout -f master`

Answer (score 1):

In a Linux environment, you can automate regular commands using [Crontabs.](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)

As a quick work around, as you appear to want to just offer a complete copy of your GIT but from your own domain, you can do this in a Crontab and set it to run every 10 minutes:

```
git --work-tree=/local/path --git-dir=/local/path/.git pull origin master
```

And copy it to your /local/path.